# Combining flutter bloc forEach() with another await

Tags: flutter, bloc, rxdart

Imagine I've got a (contrived) state that looks something like:

```
class UserState {
  final String? name;
  final String? address;
}
```

The source for `name` comes from a single (asynchronous) API call, but the `address` field value comes from a stream. Conceptually, the bloc might emit the following:

```
UserState(name: null,   address: null)
UserState(name: null,   address: 'New York')
UserState(name: 'john', address: 'New York')
UserState(name: 'john', address: 'Smith St, New York')
UserState(name: 'john', address: '10 Smith St, New York')
```

The screen that receives these states is perfectly capable of rendering itself based on the presence (or not) of `name` and `address`.

I can see that there's `emit.forEach()` that looks like it would be perfect for dealing with the stream, but I'm wrestling with how to deal with awaiting for the `fetchName()` API call.

I thought of having a local variable which keep track of whether `name` has came back (something like the following) but there's a scenario where `fetchName()` is slow and doesn't return until after all the address stream events have finished - which means I miss a state.

```
on<FetchUserEvent>((event, emit) async {
  String? name;
  fetchName().then((n) => name = n);

  emit.forEach(
    addressStream,
    onData: (a) => UserState(name: name, address: a)
  );
});
```

Is my only option to have to import RxDart just to pick up something like "combine latest"?

Am I "doing it wrong"?

Answer (score 0):

```dart
on<FetchUserEvent>((event, emit) async {
  String? name = await fetchName();

  emit.forEach(
    addressStream,
    onData: (a) => UserState(name: name, address: a)
  );
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, however, that means that the addresses don't get started to be sent back until fetching the name is complete. Ideally, I'm aiming to get states streaming back as soon as possible with whatever info we have at hand

Comment: Use can use Rx.combineLatest 

Answer (score 0):

The two calls should be separated into different events. Bloc dispatches events concurrently by default, so the following should work:

In the bloc:

```dart
on<FetchUserEvent>((event, emit) async {
  final name = await fetchName();
  emit(UserState(name: name, address: state.address));
});

on<ListenAddressEvent>((event, emit) async {
  await emit.forEach(
    event.addressStream,
    onData: (newAddress) => UserState(name: state.name, address: newAddress),
  );
});
```

And the bloc provider widget dispatches the two events eg. on create:

```dart
BlocProvider(
  create: (context) => UserBloc()
    ..add(FetchUserEvent())
    ..add(ListenAddressEvent()),
);
```

You need to use `await` before `emit.forEach`, otherwise it won't really listen. It throws an error about it if you forget as far as I remember.

Just to make sure: in this example the `FetchUserEvent` and the `ListenAddressEvent` events will start together if you use at least bloc 8.0.